# How to estimate a gas fee for transaction using opensea before sending it to the contract?

Tags: web3js, opensea

I am wondering how I can find out what the fee will be for placing a bid or selling on opensea. I retrieve the gwei using web3, but how can I get the gas limit which seems to be always very high for opensea transactions?

Is there any way I can retrieve the gas limit that is required for buying / selling on opensea before I actually send orders? Web3 for example returns gwei of 88 on average these days which would result in a few $ but when I try to use opensea I get transaction fees of $30+ because when I check the gas limit its way higherthan 21k